# find replace not working in ie

Tags: javascript, jquery

Could anyone tell me why the following code doesnt work in ie? it works in every other browser and just comes up as undefined in ie:

```
var infoTemplate = '<div style="text-align:left"><h4 style="color:#0068a6;font-size:16px;margin:0px 0px 10px 0px;">%Title</h4><strong>%Tel</strong><br /><br />%Add</div>';
var seletedMarker = null;

function composeInfoString(row) {
    var $row = $(row);
    return infoTemplate.replace('%Title', $row.find('.itemtitle a').html())
        .replace('%Tel', $row.find('.tel').html())
        .replace('%Add', $row.find('.add').html());
}
```

%Title, %Tel, %Add all come up as undefined in IE. Any help gratefully apreciated.

Comment: What do you mean they come up as undefined? Where are they being defined as anything other than a string reference?

Comment: the infoTemplate is not a jquery object

Comment: theres html which relates to this, and it finds it ok in any other browser than ie. I was hoping it would be a known syntax issue in ie :(

Comment: @bretterer That's okay, because `.replace` isn't a jQuery method.

Comment: @Blazemonger then why is the title "jquery find...."

Comment: Because inexperienced programmers often confuse jQuery and JavaScript, that's all.

Comment: You have to add the html code (and IE version), I tried this in IE 10 and it is OK:
`var a = composeInfoString('<div><div class="itemtitle"><a href="#a">aaaa</a></div><div class="tel">bbbb</div>><div class="add">cccc</div></div>');
</code>
console.log(a);`

result:
<div style="text-align:left"><h4 style="color:#0068a6;font-size:16px;margin:0px 0px 10px 0px;">aaaa</h4><strong>bbbb</strong><br /><br />cccc</div>

Comment: Post that as an answer and not a comment @PetrFort

Comment: thanks Christopher Marshall, i did.

Answer (score 0):

You have to add the html code (and IE version), I tried this in IE 10 and it is OK:

```
var a = composeInfoString('<div><div class="itemtitle"><a href="#a">aaaa</a></div><div class="tel">bbbb</div>><div class="add">cccc</div></div>');
console.log(a);
```

result:

```
<div style="text-align:left"><h4 style="color:#0068a6;font-size:16px;margin:0px 0px 10px 0px;">aaaa</h4><strong>bbbb</strong><br /><br />cccc</div>
```